# Could not load requested class exception for a class implementing Spring Security UserDetails

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-security

I use a `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` to setting up a JPA `EntityManagerFactory`.
Among the scanned entities I scan with `setPackagesToScan` I have a User entity that implement spring security interface `UserDetails`.

When I lunch my application I have this error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [com.medkhelifi.model.entities.User]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:354)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.annotations.AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.<init>(AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.java:105)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess$1.<init>(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:156)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:150)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:904)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:935)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1821)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1758)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : com.medkhelifi.model.entities.User
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl$AggregatedClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:342)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:351)
    ... 23 more
```

This is how I configured my application:
**Beans config: **

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@ComponentScan("com.medkhrlifi.tutorials.designpatterns.dao")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class AppConfig {
    // properties variable goes here ...    

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource(){
        // datasource config goes here ...
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean(){
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean lem = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        lem.setDataSource(dataSource());
        lem.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        lem.setPackagesToScan("com.medkhelifi.model.entities");
        lem.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties());
        //lem.afterPropertiesSet();
        return lem;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager platformTransactionManager(){
        JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactoryBean().getObject());
        return txManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public Properties jpaProperties(){
        Properties jpa = new Properties();
        jpa.put("hibernate.dialect", dialect);
        return jpa;
    }
}
```

**User entity**

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User implements UserDetails {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(User.class);

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private String id;

    @NotEmpty
    private String firstname;

    @NotEmpty
    private String lastname;

    @NotEmpty
    private String email;

    @NotEmpty
    private String password;


    //@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    //@Builder.Default
    @DBRef
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "user_role",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_user"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_role"))
    private List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<>();

    // Override methods goes here
}
```

** UPDATE **
I know that the error came from the UserDetails interface implementation, because if I remove it my app start normally, but this is not what I want.

This is how I run my app (for test purpose only):

```
public class DaoApp {

    private static AnnotationConfigApplicationContext applicationContext=  new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext (AppConfig.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        System.out.println("main app for test purpose only started successfully");  
    }
}
```

I hope I have provided enough information to be helped.

Comment: Are you sure that the User class is in the package com.medkhelifi.model.entities?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli yes it is.

Comment: and how you run the application? Is it Spring Boot?

Comment: No, for the moment just a main app (for test only purpose), I'll update my post to add the main app.

Comment: How do you 'scan' your entities? Need to focus on this, package name may not be correct: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : com.medkhelifi.model.entities.User vs the ComponentScan("com.medkhrlifi...

Comment: @Jayr I scan entities as mentionned in my post `lem.setPackagesToScan("com.medkhelifi.model.entities");` other entities are loaded correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bypassed the problem by removing the implementation of the `UserDetails` interface from my `User` entity, and set up a new mechanism to recover the `GrantedAuthority` necessary for Spring Security.
But I still do not understand why this interface implementation poses a problem with `setPackagesToScan` used by the JPA `EntityManagerFactory`.

If somone can give us an explanation?

Comment: Are the 'get' methods of implementation for UserDetails annotated as transient? This is weird, my guess is because UserDetails is not in the same package as your Entities, hibernate cannot load it

Comment: Even if I mark all UserDetails methods with @Transient, I still get the same error. Maybe you've right about hibernate and it's capacity to load other package classes. I'm not sure.